# How can I generate 1 mouse + 1 keyboard click?

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener, awtrobot

We are making an emulator for disabled persons. There is a desktop area in this app which we are testing at the moment. How can I programmatically generate 1 mouse click and immediately after it 1 keyboard click? Time between clicks is 100 ms.

**EDIT**

This is the code from your suggestions.

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.io.Console;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Start {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
              private final Robot robot = new Robot();

              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                robot.mousePress(1);
                robot.mouseRelease(1);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                robot.mouseMove(55, 145);
              }
            });
    }
}
```

There are 5 errors which are shown in the snapshot.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [`Robot`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class, which can be used to programmatically generate mouse clicks and keyboard strokes.  You could use this in conjunction with the Swing [`Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) class to periodically generate these events; e.g.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
  private final Robot robot = new Robot();

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    robot.mousePress(1);
    robot.mouseRelease(1);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
  }
});
```

Comment: Wow so easy :). One more thing thou, when a user mouse-clicks on some object in a real life situation, X and Y coordinates are sent along with the mouse click event. Is it possible to pass these coordinates (random ones which will go out of screen scope) along with mouse click as well?

Comment: You need to move the mouse prior to generating the click using mouseMove(int x, int y); these are screen coordinates and so you will need to do some calculations if you wish to always be clicking within your own Java application window.

Comment: The program breaks on imports. Which class should I import for Timer and Robot? I tried `import java.swing.Timer`, but it does not allow your arguments!

Comment: You need to import javax.swing.Timer.  Take a look at the JDK API docs here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/.  This will also provide information about the methods available on each class.

Comment: Hi, still errors. These are all import: import java.awt.Robot, import javax.swing.Timer. I have posted the code above for you to see it. It's simple and I do not have any idea why imports do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Robot class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html).